# Date query for a custom meta field

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, wp-query, date

I would like to use something similar to the following date_query but I would like to use some custom meta fields instead of the existing post columns. For example instead of `post_date_gmt` I would like to query the meta key `date` which I have created.

In other words, I would like to be able to filter my `custom_post_types` using some meta fields e.g. `starting_date` or `end_date` in view them in the administration interface. I have already intercept the main `WP_Query` but I am not sure how I can filter a meta field instead of a post column.

Can I do that or is it better to create a meta query?

```
// Any posts made over a year ago
// but modified in the past month
$some_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
            'before' => '1 year ago',
        ),
        array(
            'column' => 'post_modified_gmt',
            'after'  => '1 month ago',
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );
```

Comment: You need to use a `meta_query` for custom fields, and your custom field dates must be stored in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s`

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a custom meta to store the post date, rather than just using the post date?

Comment: I don't use a custom meta to store the post date, I have a new custom post e.g. Taxi reservation and I use a custom meta to store the `pickup date`. I would like to be able to filter the posts in admin interface by `meta_pickup_date` and `meta_return_date`.

Comment: @PieterGoosen can you provide a small example as well to mark your answers ? Additionally, can I have a date_query inside a meta query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to query custom fields.  If you are going to store date and time in custom fields for the purpose of ordering or comparisons, you will need to store it in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s` or as a [unix timestamp](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

If you have two custom fields `start` and `end` and you need to get posts between a cetain start and end date, you can try the following

```
$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'start',
            'value' => '2014-05-14'
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'end',
            'value' => '2015-05-07',
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ],
    ],
];

$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### FEW NOTES:

- The above requires PHP 5.4+ as it uses the new short array syntax
- The above is totally untested and might be buggy. I'm posting froma mobile device :-)
- Read the links I have supplied above

### EDIT

For some funny reason unknown, I've missed the last part of your comment.

> Additionally, can I have a date_query inside a meta query

The answer is no, but you can have a date and meta query within the same query, like this

```
$args = [
    'date_query' => [[ /* Your date related stuff */]],
    'meta_query' => [[ /* Your custom field related stuff */ ]],
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Seriously, 1000 thanks. I will test the code and I will update your answer if required. Thanks once again

Comment: No problem, feel free to make the necessary changes if needed. Enjoy :-)

Comment: You can have it also in one meta query "item" by using between :
`$meta_query[] = ['key'     => 'my_meta_key','value'   => ['2020-05-07','2020-11-07'],'type'    => 'DATETIME','compare' => 'BETWEEN'];`